# Convert column oriented table to row oriented one

Tags: sql, postgresql, tableau-api, greenplum

I have a table structure as below on Greenplum database: 
[image]

Wish to change it to the following structure so as to support pie charts on Tableau.

[image]

Could some one help me out ? Thanks!

Comment: This is called a pivot, or crosstab. No idea how to do it in Greenplum; in PostgreSQL you'd use the crosstab function in the tablefunc extension.

Comment: You can also use **unpivot**, but not giving you the exact result you want.

Comment: @KrishnrajRana . there seems to be no unpivot function in postgres . Alternative was unnest but I cant use unnest as my version of postgres is 8.2 .

Answer (score 1):

1. [Export the table to a CSV file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8119297/postgresql-export-resulting-data-from-sql-query-to-excel-csv)
2. [Install the Tableau Excel add-in](http://kb.tableausoftware.com/articles/knowledgebase/addin-reshaping-data-excel)
3. Open CSV file in Excel and use the add-in to reshape the data

Comment: I am actually connecting this data to tableau. Are there any specialized tools on tableau to achieve the same task completed

Comment: Built-in ETL capability is an oft-requested feature for Tableau Desktop and may well appear in a future version of the product, but for now it's just the Excel add-in.

Answer (score 1):

[SQL Server 2008 : Convert column value to row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13092867/sql-server-2008-convert-column-value-to-row)

http://blog.devart.com/is-unpivot-the-best-way-for-converting-columns-into-rows.html

Answer (score 0):

Just to make sure you know about this Tableau feature:

Once you have devised the SQL select statement that will unpivot the data the way you'd like, then you can tell Tableau to use that instead of a select * by editing the data connection and selecting the Custom SQL option.

The generic way to unpivot in your situation is to union together several select statements, unless your database offers a more efficient alternative as described in the blog entry that Revanayya cited.

Answer (score 0):

The following would work for a static, known beforehand, set of metrics:

```
SELECT
  t.Date,
  x.Metric,

  CASE x.Metric
    WHEN 'metric1' THEN metric1_week
    WHEN 'metric2' THEN metric2_week
  END AS week_val,

  CASE x.Metric
    WHEN 'metric1' THEN metric1_13week
    WHEN 'metric2' THEN metric2_13week
  END AS "13week_val"

FROM
  atable AS t
CROSS JOIN
  (VALUES ('metric1'), ('metric2')) AS x (Metric)
;
```

You could build a [dynamic query](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/ecpg-dynamic.html) off the above to account for an unknown number of metrics. For that, you would need to read the metadata (probably the [`INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/infoschema-columns.html) system view) to build the dynamic bits, which are the VALUES list and the two CASE expressions, before embedding them into the query.